# How can I get the types of entities in an SQLALchemy query

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I know how to get the columns that would be returned from a select statement but how do I get the entities that would be returned from an sqlalchemy.orm.Query object?

```
>>> sess = Session()
>>> q = sess.query(Entity1, Entity2)
>>> q.statement.c.keys()
['e1_col1', 'e1_col2', ..., 'e2_col1', 'e2_col2, ...]
```

I want `[Entity1, Entity2]` or something similar!

Answer (score 3):

Update: A better approach now exists, see [@exhuma answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72978285/359832). My old answer from 2010 follows.

You can try this:

```
[e.mapper.class_ for e in q._entities]
```

Although I would prefer not to use _entities attribute directly and find some other way to access it, but AFAIK there is none.

Comment: `_entities` no longer exists on the query object. This answer is obsolete. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72978285/160665

Answer (score 1):

This is indirectly available via [Query.column_descriptions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.column_descriptions):

```py
entities = {item['entity'] for item in query.column_descriptions}
```

This uses a set instead of a list to avoid duplicates in case of a query that selects specific columns (f.ex.: `query = session.query(Foo.bar, Foo.baz)`). The `column_descriptions` attribute contains an entry for each selected column so this would cause duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

sqlalchemy_utils module has a function called get_query_entities that does the job

https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/orm_helpers.html#sqlalchemy_utils.functions.get_query_entities

Comment: `get_query_entities` does not seem to exist on that library. And there is a "native" way to solve this. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72978285/160665